# Hiding certain directories in the recentf list

Tags: recentf

After every OCaml programming session, my recentf list is polluted with directories such as

```
/private/var/folders/jn/l00kvy6n15s3slnk5khz1gh00000gn/T/ocamlformatbldUeV.ml
/private/var/folders/jn/l00kvy6n15s3slnk5khz1gh00000gn/T/ocamlformatpSSLHo.ml
```

generated by `ocamlformat`. I want these to be hidden from the list, by blacklisting `/private/var/folders/`.

How can I achieve this? I have looked up functions starting with `recentf-`, but `recentf` seems to not provide any functions to do this.

Comment: @Drew Yes, it does! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate :

```
(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "/private/var/folders/.*")
```

To activate it permanently, save it in your init file (`.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`).